# Angular 2 Bind Component HTML Markup from Variable similar to innerHTML

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'd like to generically render previews based on templates saved in a database within an angular 2 component.

The idea is to save a dynamic html sub part of an ng2 components HTML within the database and bind/insert it within the component.html similar to `[innerHTML]=variable` but instead of plain HTML bind ng2 markup. So the template can access specific variables available in the component.

I'd like to avoid to write a template parser myself.

Can I bind ng2 markup with any directive similar to [innerHTML]?